# Update Button Randomly Stops Working on WooCommerce Orders Page

Tags: javascript, html

The "Update" button in WooCommerce Order page randomly stops working and throws the following error in console everytime I click on the button:

**An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.**

I read online that it has to do with some hidden but required input fields and HTML5 validation rules. But I went through all the input tags in the source code of the page when the button was not working and didn't find any such "hidden but required" input field.

I am looking for a quickfix right now, so is there anyway I can disable the browser from validating the form inputs, and allow the submit (Update) button to work always?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using this script:

```
var badForms=document.querySelectorAll("form");
for(var i=0;i<badForms.length;i++){
badForms[i].setAttribute("novalidate","novalidate");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have also come around this bug while exploring the orders page on woocommerce. So, the workaround would be to loop all the form tags and add novalidate to them.